# Draw a Connection Line in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, svg, line, raphael

How would I go about drawing a connection line in Raphael where the mousedown initiates the starting point of the line, the mousemove moves the end point without moving the start point and the mouseup leaves it as it is?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at the source of http://www.warfuric.com/taitems/RaphaelJS/arrow_test.htm.

This might get you started.

*EDIT*

I made a quick example that will give you a head start (still need some work though: validation of parameters, adding comments, etcetera).

Note: you still have to adapt the path to raphael.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="edit-Type" edit="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<!-- Update the path to raphael js -->
<script type="text/javascript"src="path/to/raphael1.4.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type='text/css'>
svg {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="raphaelContainer"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    //<![CDATA[ 

function Line(startX, startY, endX, endY, raphael) {
    var start = {
        x: startX,
        y: startY
    };
    var end = {
        x: endX,
        y: endY
    };
    var getPath = function() {
        return "M" + start.x + " " + start.y + " L" + end.x + " " + end.y;
    };
    var redraw = function() {
        node.attr("path", getPath());
    }

    var node = raphael.path(getPath());
    return {
        updateStart: function(x, y) {
            start.x = x;
            start.y = y;
            redraw();
            return this;
        },
        updateEnd: function(x, y) {
            end.x = x;
            end.y = y;
            redraw();
            return this;
        }
    };
};



$(document).ready(function() {
    var paper = Raphael("raphaelContainer",0, 0, 300, 400);
    $("#raphaelContainer").mousedown(

    function(e) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
        line = Line(x, y, x, y, paper);
        $("#raphaelContainer").bind('mousemove', function(e) {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;
            line.updateEnd(x, y);
        });
    });

    $("#raphaelContainer").mouseup(

    function(e) {
        $("#raphaelContainer").unbind('mousemove');
    });
});
    //]]> 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/rRtAq/9358/

Comment: No need for `new` in front of Raphael.
As well as in front of Line.

Answer (score 10):

You can add your own `line` method to the Paper class...

```
Raphael.fn.line = function(startX, startY, endX, endY){
    return this.path('M' + startX + ' ' + startY + ' L' + endX + ' ' + endY);
};
```

...which you can use later, like any other known method from the Paper class (circle, etc.):

```
var paper = Raphael('myPaper', 0, 0, 300, 400);
paper.line(50, 50, 250, 350);
paper.line(250, 50, 50, 150).attr({stroke:'red'});
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/f4hSM/)